# Installation of AnkhSVN Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visual-studio-2019, ankhsvn, visual-studio-2022

I can not Install AnkhSVN -Subversion Support for Visual Studio 2019,

I have tried to Install It, It says Version is Invalid for VS2019

I use VS2019 Professional

Comment: Have you tried VisualSVN for Visual Studio 2019? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualSVNLimited.VisualSVN-VS2019

Comment: Thanks in that time was not given direct yet

Comment: I'm seeing problems with creating a new Subversion repository by uploading a source code solution and associated projects with Visual Studio 2017. This seems to work fine with Visual Studio 2015. Other functions such as commits, updates, browsing seem to work fine in Visual Studio 2017 however uploading a new project causes Visual Studio 2017 to hang. I see no error messages.

Comment: which version do u have of AnkhSVN subversion, is it 2019, i installed AnkhSVN2019 from @Phil Jolans in Enterprise  vs2017 worked fine

Comment: @Phil Jolans, Guten Morgen, Hast du schon VS2022 probiert, viele Grüß von Schwabeland

Comment: @RockJunior Augen aufmachen! Ich habe die Situation für VS2022 in meiner Antwort (unten) bereits beschreiben.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I have made a fork of the AnkhSVN project and published a version on Visual Studio Marketplace as **AnkhSVN2019**.

This version targets only Visual Studio 2019.

The page on the Visual Studio Marketplace is here:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PhilJollans.AnkhSVN2019

You can also find it by searching the Visual Studio Marketplace in Visual Studio.

The project is on GitHub here:
https://github.com/PhilJollans/AnkhSVN2019

As far as I can tell it is working correctly, but that is based on a small number of systems, and I only use a subset of the features.

### Support for Visual Studio 2022

My fork of AnkhSVN does not support Visual Studio 2022, but there is a version in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/AmpScm/AnkhSVN) from the original developers of AnkhSVN.

As of 4-December-2021, this version is not available in the Visual Studio Marketplace, but you can download the package from the [releases page](https://github.com/AmpScm/AnkhSVN/releases) on GitHub.

As of 4-December-2021, the download link for the current version is
https://github.com/AmpScm/AnkhSVN/releases/download/v2.9.87/Ankh-VSIX-2022.zip,
but there may now be a newer version.

Comment: Thanks, i have tested and it seems to work great, Commit, View History works fine

Comment: Thanks a lot. Working great. This solution should marked as answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually as I can guess on the amount of recent commits on the official github, it's much more than a simple adaptation of the existing AnkhSVN project. 
I would like to be able to vote up it a thousand times, it should be the accepter answer !

Comment: Doesn't work for me. So sad. Installed it, but nothing seems to happen.VS version 16.4.1

Comment: Can you first open Extensions/Manage Extensions/Installed and check that AnkhSVN2019 is really installed and not disabled. If that is OK, can you open Tools/Source Control/Plug-in Selection. You should find AnkhSVN2019 in the list of source control plug ins. You will have to select AnkhSVN2019 as the **Current source control plug-in**.

Comment: Great, Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm using VS Community 2019 Ver. 16.8.6 and it doesnt recognized the svn repo. VS prompts extension stopped responding

Comment: Great help! thanks a lot.

Answer (score 14):

The latest AnkhSVN version is not compatible with Visual Studio 2019 (and the project, unfortunately, seems dead).

A possible solution is to edit manually the files stored in the vsix file (it's a zip file with a different extension).

The file to edit are:

- **extension.vsixmanifest**
  Change the occurance of **[15.0,16.0)** to **[15.0,17.0)**
  Change the prerequisite in this way:
  `<Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor" Version="[15.0,)" DisplayName="Visual Studio core editor" />`
- **catalog.json**
  search **Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor** and change the version to **"[15.0,)"**
- **manifest.json**
  search **Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor** and change the version to **"[15.0,)"** as the *catalog.json*

After these changes it's possible to install the extension in VS2019 but still open a warning shown by VS related an incompatibility of the load process (AnkhSVN use a synchronous load, VS2019 want an async load).

Comment: My Manifest has 15.0.25904.0     and <Prerequisites>
    <Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor" Version="[15.0.25904.1,)" DisplayName="Visual Studio core editor" />
    <Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Prerequisites" Version="[15.0.25904.0,)" DisplayName=".NET desktop development tools" />
  </Prerequisites>

Comment: I have downloaded directly the last available version from the Visual Studio Marketplace: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-303797.AnkhSVN-SubversionSupportforVisualStudio
In this package the versions are 15.0 and 16.0
I have changed the files inside this archive and I'm able to install in VS2019 (with the warning about the incompatibility as I wrote in the previous post).

Comment: Yes, and from all what i saw al numbers that i have are (16.0,17.0) and i tried to Change all but result was the same

Comment: This is very strange.
If you want try to download my version: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=99386398029505094080

This is the original version with only the change in the version of manifest and json file.

Comment: Now it is no more strange, it is working through your Installer. Thanks very much

Comment: I managed to edit the vsix and install it, but it doesn't work at all in vs2019 version 16.1.1, get loads of crashes.

Comment: With vs2019 16.1.5, "Show Changes" works fine so far, but when I bring up "View History" dialog, clicking on any entry in the list would crash vs2019. :(

Comment: When I try to run the modified .vsix file, I always gets the error, **This VSIX package is invalid because it does not contain the file extension.wsixmanifest at the root. The VSIX file may be corrupted.** I have confirmed that file exists. I have tried zipping with 7-zip and Win Desktop ``Send to -> Compressed (zipped) folder``. Any idea why this is now being flagged as an invalid archive?

Comment: I tried this and it works fine to install. Later when I add a file to a project I get System.NullReferenceException. So it does not seem to work even if you get it to install.

Comment: Additional changes needed in `extension.vsixmanifest` ` 
<InstallationTarget Version="[15.0,)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" />
    <InstallationTarget Version="[15.0,)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise" />
    <InstallationTarget Version="[15.0,)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntegratedShell" />`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59335391/461444 answer for a out of box working solution !

Answer (score 8):

Looks like it doesn't support VS2019 by default. https://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/
But you can try to update extension for VS2019.

1. Rename vsix to zip
2. Unzip
3. Open extension.vsixmanifest, manifest.json and catalog.json and for Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor change version to [15.0,)
4. Open extension.vsixmanifest and also replace all [15.0,16.0) by
   [15.0,17.0)
5. Zip all files
6. Rename to vsix

Comment: this is Manifest.json has 15.0.25904.0 and another one is <Prerequisites>
    <Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor" Version="[15.0.25904.1,)" DisplayName="Visual Studio core editor" />
    <Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Prerequisites" Version="[15.0.25904.0,)" DisplayName=".NET desktop development tools" />
  </Prerequisites>

Comment: @RockJunior if it doesn't have the second number - it's OK. So [15.0.25904.0,) - should work

Comment: not working yet but on dd_VSIInstaller.log this is log file i found tese numbers  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
  Version : [15.0,17.0)
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
  Version : [15.0,17.0)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise
 Version : [15.0,17.0)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntegratedShell
   Version : [15.0,17.0)

Comment: I missed that "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor" also present in catalog.json. Have you change this also? Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community etc. are targets for install  should. [15.0,17.0) - it's OK for targets

Comment: Now I found two numbers on "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor" in Manifest.json and Itried to Change from 16.0,17.0 to 15,0,17.0 but still did not work. and In Catalog.json there is no These numbers there is only "{"id":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.CallHierarchy,version"

Comment: @RockJunior No. "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor" should be changed to "[15.0.)". gigios answer is correct also and has good details about files

Comment: Yes I did but still does not work, Do you have this VS2019 Installed? i tried a lot

Comment: @AnkhSVN Yes. I downloaded last AnkhSVN and made all changes mentioned above and extension is appeared in VS. But I don't know how to use it, so it is untested.

Comment: @JohanDanforth looks like they are [still working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55531597/installation-of-ankhsvn-visual-studio-2019/55533335?noredirect=1#comment99383379_56141316) of support VS2019

Comment: When I try to run the modified .vsix file, I always gets the error, **This VSIX package is invalid because it does not contain the file extension.wsixmanifest at the root. The VSIX file may be corrupted.** I have confirmed that file exists. I have tried zipping with 7-zip and Win Desktop ``Send to -> Compressed (zipped) folder``. Any idea why this is now being flagged as an invalid archive?

Comment: @vik_78 yes, editor (using VS 2017) was closed before zipping.

Answer (score 7):

The original AnkhSVN project developed by CollabNet is now abandoned and does not support Visual Studio 2019 now (the project is inactive for more than 17 months). As an alternative, consider migrating to [VisualSVN](https://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) that is **now completely free for use on non-domain computers** (no registration required) and provides about the same functionality compared with AnkhSVN (some users consider VisualSVN to be better for their use cases).

Migrating from AnkhSVN to VisualSVN is a straightforward process. The most recent [VisualSVN 7.1](https://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/changes/7.1/) and [VisualSVN 6.5](https://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/changes/6.5/) releases add support for multiple working copies within a single solution, and this makes the migration practically instant and painless for almost all users. See the article [KB58: Migrating from AnkhSVN to VisualSVN](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00058/) for instructions and the article [KB7: Using Multiple Working Copies in VisualSVN](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00007/) if your solution projects span across multiple working copies.

Note that the workarounds suggested in the accepted answer may cause overall Visual Studio destabilization and do not make AnkhSVN compatible with Visual Studio 2019. See the comments under these answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/55533335/761095
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/55533472/761095

BTW, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58218456/761095), those hacky workarounds do not work anymore.

**DISCLAIMER:** I am a support engineer with VisualSVN Team.

Comment: Our company prefer AnkhSVN, thats why

Comment: Much prefer if AnkhSVN updates to use VS2019 than to pay for this. For now I'll use use TSVN.

Comment: @Harag VisualSVN is completely free on non-domain computers. Did you know that?

Comment: But with answer from  @gigios above, it is possible and i use it now for VS2019

Answer (score 6):

I've just installed AnkhSVN 2.8.12824 via "Manage Extensions". It seems to work, though Visual Studio 2019 complains that it might not be compatible with a future Visual Studio update (Deprecated APIs).

See also
https://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=582&dsMessageId=647485

Possibly also
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/synchronously-autoloaded-extensions?view=vs-2019

Comment: How exactly did you install Ankh through Manage Extensions? When I search for Ankh, nothing is found.

Comment: The owner removed the program from the marketplace until he works out the async loading in the code, according to a comment from him in the github project

Comment: Where did you get v2.8.12824?

Answer (score 4):

AnkhSVN supports Visual Studio 2019 now. Download here https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=simonp.AnkhSVN-SupportVS2019 [broken link]

Seems to still be active on GitHub: github.com/simonp22/AnkhSVN

The owner removed the program from the marketplace until he works out the async loading in the code, according to a comment from him in the github project
https://github.com/simonp22/AnkhSVN

Comment: This version was working fine under VS2019 version 16.0, but then failed on upgrade to 16.1.0 and then was automatically disabled in 16.1.1.  However, you can re-enable it via Tools>Options>Environment>Extensions and then check the box "Allow synchronous autoload". This check box might only be available in 16.1.1 and above. For more info see: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/updates-to-synchronous-autoload-of-extensions-in-visual-studio-2019/?utm_source=vs_developer_news&utm_medium=referral

Comment: Had the same issue after VS2019 16.1.0. Checked the link on the marketplace, and it is now dead. Not sure if this is going to be updated anymore.

Comment: Seems to still be active on GitHub: https://github.com/simonp22/AnkhSVN Last commit mentions start of work on background loading.

Comment: I get *We're sorry, the page you requested cannot be found!*

Comment: The owner removed the program from the marketplace until he works out the async loading in the code, according to a comment from him in the github project

Comment: I've not had any issues with AnkhSVN with VS synchronous autoload enabled.  However, it seems MS is pushing extension devs to upgrade to async.  As Johan Danforth notes, the dev says, "I’ve taken it off the marketplace whilst I figure out how to get the A-synchronous loading to work. Fairly new to this project as it was abandoned by the old developers" Link: https://github.com/simonp22/AnkhSVN/issues/9