# AnkhSVN stopped working in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visual-studio-2019, ankhsvn

The past months I have successfully been using the AnkhSVN extension in Visual Studio 2019. Yesterday the extension stopped working properly. It is still tracking which files are changed, but the Pending changes pane is not showing any content. The file list and the comment box are transparent. Show changes is working, View history has the same problem as Pending changes: a transparent pane.

I uninstalled the extension, downloaded it again, applied the changes as described in [Installation of AnkhSVN Visual Studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55531597/installation-of-ankhsvn-visual-studio-2019). I then installed it again in VS 2019. This unfortunately does not solve the problem.

Visual Studio version is 16.3.2.
AnkhSVN extension version is 2.7.12815.35086.

How can I get the AnkhSVN extension working properly again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installation of AnkhSVN Visual Studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55531597/installation-of-ankhsvn-visual-studio-2019)

Comment: Unfortunately not. That describes how to in stall AnkhSVN in VS2019. I did that some time ago, and it did work until it stopped working about a month ago.

Comment: I have compiled a version of AnkhSVN and published it under the name [AnkhSVN2019 in Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PhilJollans.AnkhSVN2019).

Comment: Thanks. I will probably not be using it. Last month we migrated our projects from SVN to DevOps. (This was a management decision that had nothing to with AnkhSVN.)

Comment: I'm also having problems with AnkhSVN with Visual Studio 2017 when attempting to create a new repository. Works fine with Visual Studio 2015 however not with Visual Studio 2017. Other functions I've tried with Visual Studio 2017 seem to work such as Pending Changes, Updates, Commits, Browsing repository.

Answer (score 1):

AnkhSVN does not support Visual Studio 2019 now. The project is inactive, and in its current state it will not work with Visual Studio 2019 properly.

Consider migrating to [VisualSVN](https://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) that fully supports Visual Studio 2019. It is **completely free for use on non-domain computers (no registration required)** and provides about the same functionality compared with AnkhSVN. Note that some users find VisualSVN to be much better for their cases.

It is should be very easy to migrate from AnkhSVN to VisualSVN. The most recent [VisualSVN 7.1](https://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/changes/7.1/) and [VisualSVN 6.5](https://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/changes/6.5/) releases add support for multiple working copies within a single solution, and this makes the migration practically instant and painless for almost all users. See the article [KB58: Migrating from AnkhSVN to VisualSVN](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00058/) for instructions and the article [KB7: Using Multiple Working Copies in VisualSVN](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00007/) if your solution projects span across multiple working copies.

> I uninstalled the extension, downloaded it again, applied the changes
>   as described in Installation of AnkhSVN Visual Studio 2019. I then
>   installed it again in VS 2019. This unfortunately does not solve the
>   problem.

Hacking the VS2017 VSIX files by adding a few string to make this VSIX install into VS2019 is a very bad idea. This action does not magically make AnkhSVN support VS2019 - it allows its installation into VS2019. This hack may cause overall Visual Studio destabilization and unexpected problems.

**DISCLAIMER:** I am a support engineer with VisualSVN Team.

Comment: I am giving it a try. But Visual Studio showing the message _Visual Studion stopped responding for 6 seconds. Disabling the extension VisualSVN for Visual Studio 2019 7.1.2.44 might help._ several times within half an hour does not sound very promising.

Comment: I tried Visual SVN but AnkhSVN found much better so using @phil-jollans 's forked version of AnkhSVN https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55531597/installation-of-ankhsvn-visual-studio-2019. VisualSVN should improve their icons. Multiproject commit in the solution requires separate commited when there in difference folder hirarchy.

Comment: We migrated to Git, so we are no longer using SVN.