# How to install ankhsvn into Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

Refer to [Installation of AnkhSVN Visual Studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55531597/installation-of-ankhsvn-visual-studio-2019), although it can be successfully installed, it still cannot be used in visual studio 2022

[image]

ActivityLog.xml:

CreateInstance failed for package [AnkhSVN - Subversion Support for Visual Studio]Source: 'mscorlib' Description: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///c:\users\xxxx\appdata\local\microsoft\visualstudio\17.0_1d0575ca\extensions\mhbmk1bf.g1d\Ankh.Package.dll' or one of its dependencies.

Answer (score 30):

According to the authors it will be on the Market place soon. For now use the direct installation link (uzip and execute). https://github.com/AmpScm/AnkhSVN/releases/download/v2.9.87/Ankh-VSIX-2022.zip

Answer (score 2):

The version linked in the Gutek answer (https://github.com/AmpScm/AnkhSVN/releases/download/v2.9.87/Ankh-VSIX-2022.zip) don't work well with Visual Studio 2022, when opening VS2022 it gives several errors (https://github.com/AmpScm/AnkhSVN/issues/44)

At the moment, for Visual Studio 2022, they recommend to install the latest version built correctly and is available in https://github.com/AmpScm/AnkhSVN/actions (the vsix are in the artifacts of a successfully build)

Comment: At this time : "This artifact has expired and you can no longer download it"...

Comment: Tip You need to log into GitHub be able to access the latest build.

Answer (score -1):

From the [extension page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-303797.AnkhSVN-SubversionSupportforVisualStudio&ssr=false#overview), AnkhSVN does not support visual studio 2022. And I suggest you can leave this question here: [AnkhSVN - Subversion Support for Visual Studio Q&A](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-303797.AnkhSVN-SubversionSupportforVisualStudio&ssr=false#qna)

Comment: Incorrect.  See other answer.